# Calculating info_hash from UrlEncoded query string

Tags: c#, tracker, info-hash

Basically, I'm building a small tracker for experimental purposes. I've gotten quite far, and am now working on the announce part.

What I really can't figure out is how I should decode the info_hash query string provided.

From the specification, it is a *urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash*, which made me write this code,

```
byte[] foo = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(infoHash));
string temp = "";

foreach (byte b in foo)
{
    temp += b.ToString("X");
}
```

Which gives 'temp' the following value,

```
5D3F3F3F3F5E3F3F3F153FE4033683F55693468
```

The first and last few characters are correct. This is the raw info_hash,

```
%5d%96%b6%f6%84%5e%ea%da%c5%15%c4%0e%403h%b9Ui4h
```

And this is what both uTorrent and my own tracker gives me as info_hash when generating it from the torrent file,

```
5D96B6F6845EEADAC515C40E403368B955693468
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UrlDecode returns a string, but a SHA1 hash doesn't make sense if interpreted as (ANSI) string.
You need to decode the input string directly to an byte array, without the roundtrip to a string.

```
var s = "%5d%96%b6%f6%84%5e%ea%da%c5%15%c4%0e%403h%b9Ui4h";

var ms = new MemoryStream();
for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == '%')
    {
        ms.WriteByte(
            byte.Parse(s.Substring(i + 1, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
        i += 2;
    }
    else if (s[i] < 128)
    {
        ms.WriteByte((byte)s[i]);
    }
}

byte[] infoHash = ms.ToArray();
string temp = BitConverter.ToString(infoHash);
// "5D-96-B6-F6-84-5E-EA-DA-C5-15-C4-0E-40-33-68-B9-55-69-34-68"
```

Comment: Thanks! The example works like a charm, although when replacing the hard coded string with the info_hash query string, it gets all messed up.

    var s = context.Request.QueryString["info_hash"]

Gives me a string of gibberish, not the string value of the query string.

Comment: Never mind, I went with the context.Request.Query route instead. Guess I'll have to parse it from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tzbke5e.aspx)